# Tizen IVI 3.0 porting for ARM

Tags: linux, x86, arm, tizen

Tizen 3.0 IVI is available for x86 platform (May be intended to be deployed in x86 based phones). As a part of my work, am trying to port the whole tizen software for ARM.

From the Tizen [help documentation](https://source.tizen.org/documentation/developer-guide/creating-tizen-platform-image-scratch-through-local-build), i see the build tooling (MIC and GBS) supports ARM cross compilation also. But, when i try to build for Tizen 3.0, it is failing with dependency errors.

Further Analysis: With further analysis into the GBS tooling and the tizen software, i see all the toolchain (named as pre-builts) are available only for x86 platform but not for ARM platform. So i started building the toolchain for ARM (with the help of Buildroot and pre-existing ARM cross compiler from crosstool-ng sysroot). Due to many cyclic dependency between all the packages (RPMS), i am unable to proceed further.

My Question: Does anybody tried this already? Is there any way to build the Tizen 3.0 for ARM (Compiling for IMX6)? Does the Tizen build tool really supports for ARM?

Comment: You might want to try the Tizen developer's forum.

Answer (score 0):

I assume porting to ARM will be a big job and would recommend Automotive Grade Linux (AGL) for running Tizen on the ARM. AGL is derived from the Tizen IVI.

Comment: This is a bit short on detail. Are you saying "Someone's already done this, and they call it Automotive Grade Linux"?

Comment: Hi..Although Tizen is claimed to be multi-platform but mainly Intel platform is in focus as of day. Simple reason is Intel collaborated with Samsung for the Tizen development. Please refer to Automotive Grade Linux (AGL) website http://automotive.linuxfoundation.org/ for more details. Also the hardware platform is available for the ARM http://automotive.linuxfoundation.org/node/47